# I am unable to see all Projects under my dashboard in google cloud console even though i have the Organization Administrator role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

When i got to https://console.cloud.google.com/ and select from organization.com i do not see all the projects. Is there a way to view and work on those projects?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your display is defaulting to only the most recent projects. There's another "tab" that should display all projects in your org.

[image: Resource Manager modal has an "All" tab]